# RxJS endless loop from Array with delay based on value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to endlessly loop over a Array that contains Entries where each of them has a specified time duration to be active. Once this duration has passed, the next Entry should be emitted. I was able to get it working when I limit the number of Entries taken from the stream but it fails with `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` if I want it to run endlessly.

The use-case is to have a fixed set of pages, each with its own duration for which it should be visible. Once the last page has been shown, it should start again with the first page, and so on ....

This is my attempt at creating this stream:

```
import { from, of, zip } from "rxjs";
import { map, startWith, share, concatMap, delay, repeat, take } from "rxjs/operators";

interface Entry {
  name: string;
  duration: number;
}
const data: Array<Entry> = [
  {"name": "foo", "duration": 1000},
  {"name": "bar", "duration": 4000},
  {"name": "bla", "duration": 2000}
];

const source = from(data).pipe(
  repeat(),
  take(10),
  share()
);
const ticker = source.pipe(
  map(v => v.duration),
  startWith(0),
);

zip(source, ticker).pipe(
  concatMap(([val, dur]) => of(val).pipe(delay(dur))),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x, new Date()));
```

It works because of `take(10)` in the `source` stream. Removing it causes the `RangeError`.

The expected output should be like this:

```
{ name: 'foo', duration: 1000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:37.284Z
{ name: 'bar', duration: 4000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:38.289Z
{ name: 'bla', duration: 2000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:42.294Z
{ name: 'foo', duration: 1000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:44.297Z
{ name: 'bar', duration: 4000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:45.297Z
{ name: 'bla', duration: 2000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:49.303Z
{ name: 'foo', duration: 1000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:51.307Z
{ name: 'bar', duration: 4000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:52.310Z
{ name: 'bla', duration: 2000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:56.316Z
{ name: 'foo', duration: 1000 } 2023-10-03T20:54:58.320Z
...continue until unsubscribed...
```

Is there a better way to emit from the repeating `source` while still maintaining the delay based on the last emitted Entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andrei pointed out, you stack problem comes from the `repeat()` creating an infinite amount of entries before they hit the concatMap.

Since you have the duration already in the `Entry` you can simplify your solution getting rid of the ticker like this:

```
const source = from(data).pipe(
  concatMap((entry) => of(entry).pipe(delay(entry.duration))),
  repeat(),
  share()
); 

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x, new Date()));
```

Or if you want to emit the entry and then wait:

```
concatMap((entry) => concat(of(entry),timer(entry.duration).pipe(ignoreElements()))),
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 12s haha https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jbaayj?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts , have my upvote

Comment: @maxime1992‍ :)

Comment: Thanks! Getting rid of the ticker was really a boon for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is repeat() basically creates an infinite number of events, that are pushed to operators after it up to `concatMap` callback. Rxjs streams are conceptually push based, and it is kinda impossible to know how your emitted events are handled or delayed. that is why you basically have to limit events on the step of repeating.

A useful feature of the repeat operator for your case would be `repeat({delay: time})`. To repeat the source only after they overall duration

```
const sumDur = data.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.duration, 0);
const source = from(data).pipe(
  repeat({delay: sumDur}),
  take(10),
  share()
);
```

Or you could try to modify the solution to `repeat` only at the end of the stream after all delays